# C# Chart Control Label Repeat

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

I am developing windows form application with C#. My application uses Chart Control but there is a problem.

I add a series (CharType is Line) to the Chart Control and then later draw my currrent series on the Plot Area.

A label is shown upon the series line, but I want to show label name only once. What should I do to show label name once?

Comment: So you have the Series line labeled in the Legend of the Chart? But you don't want it labeled anywhere else? I'm just trying to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//remove all labels on chart
foreach (DataPoint item in chart1.Series[0].Points)
{
    item.Label = "";
}

//alternatively disable all labels
chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel == false
```

Now add label to last point. You could pick any `Chart1.Series[0].Points[i]` to put the label on, but in this example it adds the label to the last point

```
_Point Point = chart1.Series[0].Points[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 1];
_Point.Label = chart1.Series[0].Name;
```